# ArrayList change values when i add a new one VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

So here is my problem. I have a Class of Products and i have created an ArrayList of that class.
I can add lot of new Products to that Array but the problem is that the Array change all the Values of the Array as the last one i have added.

Product Class:

```
Public Class Product
Dim cod_prod As String
Dim state As Boolean

Public Sub New(ByVal cod As String, ByVal est As Boolean)
    cod_prod = cod
    state = est
End Sub

Public Sub New()
    cod_prod = ""
    state = False
End Sub

Public Function get_cod_prod() As String
    Return cod_prod
End Function

Public Function get_state() As Boolean
    Return state
End Function

Public Sub set_cod_prod(ByVal cod As String)
    cod_prod = cod
End Sub

Public Sub set_state(ByVal est As Boolean)
    state = est
End Sub
End Class
```

And this class is were i add a new Product to the ArrayList.

```
 Dim array_prod As New ArrayList
 Dim nproducts As Integer = 0

 Public Sub add_prod(ByVal prod As Producto)
    array_prod.Add(prod)
    nproducts += 1
 End Sub
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: try this  :
   Dim array_prod() As New ArrayList

Comment: no, that makes a compilation error.

Comment: i can't see that the variable 'array_prod' is an array

Comment: its declared as an ArrayList and i can have lot of products on it look.

Comment: ah ok sorry , i understand

Comment: I didn't work with ArrayList before, try if this work :

    Dim array_prod As New List(Of Product)

    Public Sub add_prod(ByVal prod As Product)
        array_prod.Add(prod)
    End Sub
    ' to get the number of product in the list :
    Dim N = array_prod.Count

Comment: The symptoms you describe suggest that each time you add a Producto to the array, it's actually the same instance each time.  So show us the code that actually calls add_prod.  The code you have shown us so far looks okay

Comment: i have found the answer xd

Comment: You should definetly look at properties. You don't need to create a function for every get and set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looking a bit more on related questions i have found this. 
[Retrieving data from a VB.NET arraylist of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062320/retrieving-data-from-a-vb-net-arraylist-of-objects?rq=1)

So i solve it changing the method like this:

```
Public Sub add_prod(ByVal prod As Producto)
    Dim nprod As New Producto
    nprod.set_cod_prod(prod.get_cod_prod)
    nprod.set_state(prod.get_state)

    array_prod.Add(nprod)
    nproductos += 1
End Sub
```